# vscode WorkspaceConfiguration.update - values not updated?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My VS Code extension updates some workplace folder-specific settings. My code for doing this - it reports the updated values on the status bar.

EDIT: updated to use async / await and repeatedly try to get the new value.
This showed me that it's necessary to "refresh" the configuration object itself by calling

```js
cfg = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();
```

after setting the value. otherwise .get() returns the old value.

This now works as expected

```js
export async function setEmailDesignSystemId(cfg: vscode.WorkspaceConfiguration, bar: vscode.StatusBarItem, value?: string) {
    if (value) {
        var [id, descr] = splitBySemiColon(value);
        const idNum = parseInt(id, 10);
        try {
            // null enables resource per workspace / workspace folder
            await cfg.update('designSystemId', idNum, null);
            await cfg.update('designSystemDescr', descr, null);
            console.log(`Set EDS ID = ${idNum}, descr = ${descr}`);
            // MUST refresh the cfg object to see the new values
            cfg = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('taxi');
            updateEDSBar(bar, cfg, '');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('failure updating designSystemId');
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to call the `update` functions using `async/await` approach instead of `.then` (promises)?

Comment: now using await (see above). The trick was you need to `getConfiguration` after updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the answer in the "edit" above.

When you call `cfg.update`, VS Code writes your changes to persistent storage (e.g. the `settings,json` file). It does not change the `cfg` object contents itself.

You therefore need to

- `await` the changes
- call `.getConfiguration` again to refresh your local object.